# Problems with modals inside tabel, getting them to fill the box

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, html-table

I'm using bootstrap, and their modal. I'm trying in the most optimal way to make a table which you can click on which would then open the modal. I would like to make a study calendar, but I have just begun with html coding.
This is my code:

```
   </head>

  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">    Studieplan - Din kontakt til studiet</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Hjem</a></li>
            <li><a href="#afleveringer">Afleveringer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#indstillinger">Indstillinger</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->

    <div class="container">

      <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
          <p class="pull-right visible-xs">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="offcanvas">Toggle nav</button>
          </p>
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Studieplan</h1>
          </div>

    </div><!--/.container-->
    <table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Mandag</th>
        <th>Tirsdag</th>
        <th>Onsdag</th>
        <th>Torsdag</th>
        <th>Fredag</th>
        <th>Lørdag</th>
        <th>Søndag</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><!-- Mandag 09/12-2013-->
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#Mandag" data-keyboard="" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Mandag 09/12-2013</a>

            <div id="Mandag" class="modal modal-wide fade">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><b><center>Mandag 09/12-2013</center></b></h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                     <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                        <th>Fag</th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th>Lektier</th>
                                        <th>Afleveringer</th>
                                      </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            1 - Programmering, 08:00  -  08:50 - Lok: MU9-12, Lærer: bj<br> <br>
                                                    2 - Programmering, 08:55  -  09:50 - Lok: MU9-12, Lærer: bj<br> <br>
                                                    3 - Fysik, 09:55 - 10:45  -  Lok: MU9-110, Lærer: smo<br><br>
                                                    4 - Fysik, 10:50 - 11:40  -  Lok: MU9-110, Lærer: smo<br><br>
                                                    5 - Kemi, 12:05 - 12:55  -  Lok: MU9-127, Lærer: suh<br><br>
                                                    6 - Kemi, 13:00 - 13:50  -  Lok: MU9-127, Lærer: suh<br><br>
                                                    7 - Matematik, 14:00 - 14:50  -  Lok: MU9-129, Lærer: sbj<br><br>
                                                    8 - Matematik, 14:55 - 15:45  -  Lok: MU9-129, Lærer: sbj<br><br>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        Lektie Industrialiseringen på Fyn Gruppe-delprojekt. <br>
                                            Uddannelsestid: 3,33 timer.<br>
                                            Elevtid: 2,5 timer.<br>
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Tilføj lektier</button>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <b>Teknologihistorie </b><br>
                                            Industrialiseringen på Fyn Gruppe-delprojekt. <br>
                                            Uddannelsestid: 3,33 timer.<br>
                                            Elevtid: 2,5 timer.<br> <br>

                                            Opgaveformulering: Se vedhæftede fil<br>
                                            Word-dokumentindustrialiseringen på Fyn.doc
                                        </td>
                                     </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
              </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
</td>
```